# Kunneth formula for arbitrary tensor products of chain complexes

Tags: homological-algebra

Over a field, taking homology commutes with the tensor product of two chain complexes by the Künneth formula: $H(C_*\otimes D_*)\cong H(C_*)\otimes H(D_*)$.

Does this extend to arbitrary tensor products of chain complexes, i.e. do we have $H(\otimes_iC^i_*) \cong \otimes_iH(C_*^i)$?

Comment: For finite tensor products the answer is yes. It is just a simple induction argument.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that. I was really wondering about infinite tensor products. I suppose I should've clarified that in the question, sorry @Gustavo

Comment: (Filtered) direct limits are exact and thus commute with taking homology.

Comment: What's your definition of an infinite tensor product?